# How to add and use new build of OpenCV that includes OpenCV-Contrib in IDE (PyCharm)?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, opencv-contrib

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5EWlNQ6z5w&ab_channel=AdamHacks that describes how to build opencv to include in that the features from non-free opencv-contrib and got no errors with doing that. The problem is that I don't really know what I need to in the next step to be able to use in my IDE (PyCharm) the new build of opencv.

I saw that on official opencv-contrib repository on github exist a tutorial and says this on 8th step

> To run, linker flags to contrib modules will need to be added to use them in your code/IDE. For example to use the aruco module, "-lopencv_aruco" flag will be added.

But that does not say pretty much for me. Can somebody explain me the steps I need to follow from here to be able to use for example "xfeatures2d" from opencv-contrib in my PyCharm IDE?